# How to interact with 'dynamically created objects' in c# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am quite new to C# and am stuck at the following problem: Out of data my program creates at runtime a dictionary of objects (of unknown size). For each of the objects I want to create a StackPanel Element with two TextBoxes inside, which I do as follows:

```
foreach (string name in a.Keys){
    StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
    TextBox TB1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox TB2 = new TextBox();
    SP.Children.Add(TB1);
    SP.Children.Add(TB2);
    // ... Content to TextBoxes 
    TB2.Name = name;
}
```

Now, somewhere else in the program I put a Checkbox, that should toggle if the 2nd Textbox in each StackPanel above is visible, e.g., by something like this:

```
void MainCheckBox_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    if (MainCheckBox.IsChecked == true){XXX.Height = 300;}
    else {XXX.Height = 0;}
}
```

XXX here should be a reference to the TextBox that is called 'TB2'. But using any 'name' from the list (which should correspond to be the name of a TB2) does not work, the compiler says that 'name' does not exist, even if I literally use a concrete name from the list, like 'John' (assuming he is in the list).

I assume I am doing something conceptually wrong, so what is a better way to create such things depending on the data?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You could store all the `TB2`'s in a `HashSet<TestBox>`, and iterate through it when needed.

Comment: @Vlad: Why `HashSet` and not just a `List`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: well, I assumed one will need to add/delete the items from the container. For the case of "static" container, the `List` is indeed better.

Comment: @Vlad: Still cannot quite see the advantage of a `HashSet`. You don't gain anything of `HashSet`'s hashing capabilities, after all (or are hash values of text boxes automatically based on their name?), so the `HashSet` probably does a lot of extra work when adding items by sorting them into appropriate buckets etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: HashSet has quick insertion/deletion, whereas List hasn't.

Comment: @Vlad: [This](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/) and [this](http://softscenario.blogspot.de/2009/05/performance-testing-of-dictionary-list.html) seem to suggest otherwise for insertion, but if `HashSet` is really faster, I agree and it will be up to the OP to determine whether the number of elements in his or her list really reach into ranges where these performance differences are notable enough to justify the unclean code due to the workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to keep the reference to the `TextBox` objects that you create.  E.g. you could create a `Dictionary<string, TextBox>` to store the references:

```
private Dictionary<string, TextBox> myTextBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
```

When you create your `TextBox` objects, you would add them to the dictionary:

```
myTextBoxes.Add(name, TB2);
```

you would then access your `TextBox` like this:

```
myTextBoxes["TextBoxName"].Height = 300;
```

Comment: why `Dictionary` and not just a `HashSet`?

Comment: @Vlad - HashSets don't have indexes.  You would not be able to do this with a `HashSet`: `myTextBoxes["TextBoxName"].Text = "New text for TextBox"`

Comment: BTW, this wouldn't work, as you are overwriting the item (name is always the same). (The OP doesn't need to access individual textboxes, he needs only all of them.)

Comment: @Vlad - `name` represents the `name` that the OP used in the question.  How do you know it is always the same?

Comment: sorry, I'm taking my comment back -- the names are really different, as they are the keys in the outer dictionary.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks, your answer is the one I went with and it works fine... I had thought of this, but stopped trying, because it didn't work - now I realize my tiny error... Damn.

Comment: when doing wpf you should not go this way, but thats just my thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to iterate through all controls and then check for type and for name (or a tag which u provide to the control). then u can normally handle the control. for iterating i would use the following:

```
    foreach(TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Name.Equals("SEARCHEDNAME")))
        {
            //Do something with the control and then u can break
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either search WPF's VisualTree to find the object with your name (I have some [`VisualTreeHelpers` on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) you might find useful, and they show some Visual Tree Navigation examples)

```
var tb = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<TextBox>(this, tbName);
if (tb != null)
    tb.Height = (MainCheckBox.IsChecked ? 300 : 0);
```

Or you can take advantage of WPF's binding system to do this for you. Personally I'd do this with a Style if you're making the controls in code-behind

```
<Style x:Key="SecondTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="300" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then when you create your TextBoxes:

```
TB2.Style = this.FindResource("SecondTextBoxStyle") as Style;
```

In an ideal world, I wouldn't even use code-behind to make the objects. Instead I'd use an `ItemsControl` bound to your `Keys` ObservableCollection, and set the `ItemTemplate` to whatever you want.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox ... />
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource SecondTextBoxStyle}" ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel, this answer sounds intriguing, but I don't fully understand it yet as I am not soo deep into WPF yet. I will definitely try to understand it as my own understanding progresses and implement it then.

Comment: @ToaoG No problem :) The important thing to realize with WPF applications is they have two layers: the UI layer and the Data layer. Typically you want to keep both layers completely separate, and bindings are used to connect the data layer to the UI layer. If you end up doing a lot of WPF development, I'd highly recommend the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

the easy way would be to take the dynamic created objects - put them in a collection - create a datatemplate, so that wpf knows how to render - and put these collection to a itemscontrol. some call this mvvm with viewmodel first ;)

your dynamic object wrapper

```
public class MyObject //should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
  //your public properties goes here
}
```

your viewmodel which handles collection and retrieving data for the collection

```
public class MyViewmodelWithDynamicCollection //should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyItems {get;set;}//just init once and add, remove, clear like you want

}
```

in your view resources

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyObject}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyReadonlyProperty}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyEditableProperty}"/>
    </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

in your view

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"/>
```

thats all

Comment: if you have different MyObject classes - no problem - you can take a base class type for the collection or object type. you just have to create one datatemplate for each MyObject class.

Comment: @your checkbox requirement: every MyObject should implement a bool property - in the datatemplate the textbox should have a datatrigger to set visibility - when checkbox is checked you can iterate through the collection and set the bool property. thats all

Comment: Thanks Blindmeis! This answer also seems pretty good to me, but I am still lacking some WPF to understand it fully. I am more comfortable in the C# coding...

Answer (score 0):

Once you store an object in the dictionary, the name is just the key in the dictionary. This has no implications to the compiler; the name is no known identifier to the compiler.

The same applies to the value you assign to the `Name` property of the control. To the compiler, that is just an ordinary string that could just as well be a help text; the compiler does not consider it any special just because the property is called `Name`.

You can retrieve an object from the dictionary with an expression such as `a["myName"]`; and you can find a control with a particular name (as per the `Name` property) by iterating over all controls and comparing the value of their `Name` property.

If you have to frequently access those controls, it might be worth setting up an additional dictionary where you store the controls by their names (e.g. `Dictionary<string, TextBox>`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're saying the same as Kevin above, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of workarounds provided in other answers; they more or less solve your problem. One more workaround:

```
foreach (string name in a.Keys){
    StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
    TextBox TB1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox TB2 = new TextBox();
    SP.Children.Add(TB1);
    SP.Children.Add(TB2);
    // ... Content to TextBoxes
    TB2.Name = name;
    MainCheckBox.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
        TB2.Height = MainCheckBox.IsChecked ? 300 : 0;
    }
}
```

But let's see what should be the correct way.

First of all, you need the data items to be presented in a bindable form. This means either derive from `DependencyObject` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Second, you need to put your objects into an `ObservableCollection`. Then, you can use different containers like `ListView` or `ListBox` for displaying the collection of data. For the type representing the data item, you'd need to create a `DataTemplate`, in which you can put any custom logic you need.

You see that this is quite a lot of work, so I wouldn't recommend this approach for really small applications; however as your application grows, this approach will show its benefits.

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Indeed my project is not so big as to have the need to implement all this machinery, but I do like your answer. As I progress in my understanding of the subject, I will definitely try to implement this approach once...